# PHP how to check if a returned row contains duplicate values?

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?php
include('includes/connection.php');

$query = 'select a, c from b';
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0)
{
    echo '<p>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
         echo "{$row["a"]}";
    }
    echo '</p>';
}
?>
```

Table "b" has these values in column "a"

```
Table b
-------
a     c
-     -
1     a
1     a1
1     a2
2     a
3     b
4     b
```

I would like to be able to in my while loop determine if the returned row is a duplicate and discard it. I only want the number 1 in this case to show up once. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT`.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: and i hope you are using 'real' table and field names.

Comment: Yeah I am, I just just used that as an example since it was easier to type than the full names.

Comment: Add `GROUP BY a` to the end of your query, if any value in `c` for a duplicate `a` would do

Answer (score 2):

You should do this on the sql side since the db servers are optimized to run this kind of operations rather than use iterations and validations in the php side.  Use DISTINCT in your sql select.

Comment: I've updated my question I actually have a second column there that contains different data as well. So say I want a, a1 and a2 because they are all part of 1 but I only want it to print 1 once. Do I need another table for this? It is even possible with just this one table?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think distinct will be helpful in your case.The reason is distinct works on elements having exact equal rows,but as in your case even if your column a matches your column c does nt

A distinct on a and c will give 3 row for 1(in a column).

I may be overdoing it but this i came up with

Loop through `a`

```
  FOR x IN (SELECT a from table)

SELECT *   FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY user_id) user_row_no, A.* FROM table A WHERE A.a=x.a )  


END LOOP;
```